# Interpretation of glm coefficients against mean of bootstrap fitted coefficients

Tags: r, glm, coefficients

I have a landslide model with a response and 5 predictor variables (slope...log10_carea). I ran my data through `glm` and returned the fitted coefficients.

In addition, i am tasked to generate 1000 bootstrap samples from the training data and compute the mean of fitted coefficients for each sample.

How do the fitted coefficients from my original data compare to the mean values of the bootstrap coefficients calculated? what can i interpret from these fitted coefficients?

[image]

Any insight will be helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: Questions about interpretation of statistical results are more at home at Cross Validated, so I've voted to migrate this question.

Comment: how do i migrate this question to stack exchange? @Lyngbakr

Comment: I don't think you can. Users with sufficient reputation vote for migration and, so far, you have three votes. I believe you need one more.